# Collect data from facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, data-extraction

I want to write a program(no restriction on language) to extract data from facebook pages( name, website URL associated with facebook page, category that facebook page is listed in, Location of facebook page).
I want to know that is it possible to access data of all facebook pages in a particular area. Basically I know that we need ID of a facebook page to access data of that page. My question  is how do I get a list of IDs of all facebook pages ?

Comment: Make sure you have read and understood the Facebook *terms of service*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is how do I get a list of IDs of all facebook pages ?

Not possible.

> I want to know that is it possible to access data of all facebook pages in a particular area.

Again, not possible